# How to not update the value with null even if i click back button?

Tags: php, html, sql, button, sql-update

I've currently an edit page where the user can update their values in the box as provided. There is a submit button , which **successfully updates** the value inserted, and a back button, which brings me back to the previous menu. The thing is, if I click the back button, it will just automatically redirect me back to the previous menu, and updating all the values to null, this isn't what I want it to be, please help me shed some pointers on this, thanks!

PHP CODE

```
<div class = "form-group">
    Book Title 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookTitle" name="bookTitle" 
        value= "<?php if (isset($_POST['bookTitle'])) echo($_POST['bookTitle']); ?>" 
        placeholder="" required>
```

HTML Code

```
           <form class="form-horizontal" action="" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class = "form-group">
            Book Title <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookTitle" name="bookTitle" value= "<?php if (isset($_POST['bookTitle'])) echo($_POST['bookTitle']); ?>" placeholder="" required>
            </div>
            </div>
```

SQL Statement

```
$sql = "UPDATE `allbooks` SET `allbooks`.bookTitle = '$bookTitle', WHERE `allbooks`.id = $id";
                    if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) 
                     {
                        if ($test == true)
                        {
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Record updated successfully";
                        }
                     }
```

Comment: `updating the values to null`. In the mySQL database or on your html form?

Comment: in the MYSQL Database once i click the back button, then in my html form it updates all my data as null

Comment: Why is there even a mySQL statement executed when you click the back button? I think we're going to need to see exactly how your files interact (e.g. where is the PHP backend for your form?) to help you further.

Comment: Hi Huey, there is no php backend file for my form. If it is, it is indicated in the PHP code as above.

Comment: Where does `$_POST['booktitle']` become $bookTitle? And I suppose the SQL bit is in the same file as the PHP bit.

Comment: $_POST ['booktitle'] becomes $bookTitle so I can store the variable inside the SQL statement :) and yes the SQL is in the same file as PHP bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to test for the necessary values before running the sql, if I am understanding you right.

```
if(!empty($bookTitle)){
    $sql = "UPDATE `allbooks` SET `allbooks`.bookTitle = '$bookTitle', WHERE `allbooks`.id = $id";
    if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
        if ($test == true){
            echo "<p>Record updated successfully</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Then it will only run if there is a value. Don't forget to sanitize your input to avoid SQL injection!

Comment: Hi Greene, I've done an empty check even previously before I asked this question, and it still enables me to click the back button **and** still updating all the values to "Null"

Comment: Thank you greene, I solved it by using your !empty, totally forgetting I can just put a if statement before the SQL statement before it runs!